# How to execute JAVA programs with Inner classes?

Tags: java

I have 3 classes in my program

```
1. LinkedListProgram : contains PSVM 
2. LinkedList extends Node { 
     3. private class Node {
       }   
   }
```

I am compiling the java program by the following command

```
javac -d bin .\LinkedListProgram.java
```

The compilation is successful and I see 3 .class files inside my bin folder

```
LinkedList$Node.class
LinkedList.class
LinkedListProgram.class
```

Now I want to execute the program and the command I use is

```
java -cp bin LinkedListProgram
```

This gives me a stack trace error , I am pasting it below

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Node
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at LinkedListProgram.main(LinkedListProgram.java:137)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Node
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 13 more
```

How to fix this ? From what I experimented, if I DONT generate the .class file in another directory, the java program runs okay.

What is wrong in my way of running the program from the bin folder ?

The full source code can be seen in [Github](https://github.com/sunandanbarman/DataStructures/blob/master/LinkedListProgram.java)

I feel it is not a very good idea to paste the whole code in my OP, since the code is a bit lengthy. Please go to the link above for the full code.

Comment: Show us the code, in which package are the classes ?

Comment: I agree with @Marged if you need help you need to show some code, with what you write make the chance of answering very limited.

Comment: the code is in default package.

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs because you are trying to extend a inner class from its parent class.

```
LinkedList extends Node {
    class Node{}     
}
```

Information: Private inner classes exist **only** in context of their parent classes, so that means that `Node` is not visible outside `LinkedList`. ***Not even at the parent class definition!***

But the real problem is not that Node is private,

Lets say you make `Node` class `public`, this will allow you to refer to your inner class when defining your parent class like this `LinkedList extends LinkedList.Node`.
But this will result to having a *cyclic reference* from `LinkedList` to *itself*. Which is **not** allowed !!!

The solution to this is to place the two classes in seperate files.

In your case, in which you have all classes in one file just place the `Node` class definition after (or before) the `LinkedList` class definition

Comment: But then if I do not specify "bin" as output directory explicitly, then it works. Why is that ?

Comment: You are right, I had not read your question correctly and thought that Node was defined as an inner class somewhere else. I have now updated my answer